# Getting error when trying to update the PFX cert in CACERTS

Tags: certificate

I am trying to enable SSL in my application for which i have to update the PFX cert in CACERTS. Below are the steps I did but I am getting below error
when trying to import the PFX in CACERTS.

> "keytool error: java.lang.Exception: Input not an X.509 certificate"

1. Create a jks file and generate a CSR from that JKS

   *keytool -genkeypair -alias abc03.dc.abc.com -keyalg RSA -keystore /opt/logo/certificates/abc03.dc.abc.com.jks -keysize 2048 -dname "CN=abc03.dc.abc.com,O=DT,L=xxx,ST=xxx,C=xxx" -ext san=dns:abc03.dc.abc.com*

   *keytool -certreq -alias abc03.dc.abc.com -keystore /opt/logo/certificates/abc03.dc.abc.com.jks -file /opt/logo/certificates/abc03.dc.abc.com.csr -ext san=dns:abc03.dc.abc.com -ext EKU=serverAuth,clientAuth*
2. Get it signed by CA
3. Import the root , Intermediate & server cert into the jks that i created

   *keytool -import -keystore abc03.dc.abc.com.jks -alias root -file root.cer
   keytool -import -keystore abc03.dc.abc.com.jks -alias intermediate -file intermediate.cer
   keytool -import -keystore abc03.dc.abc.com.jks -alias mykey -file abc03.dc.abc.com.cer*
4. convert the JKS to PKCS12

   *keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore abc03.dc.abc.com.jks -destkeystore abc03.dc.abc.com.p12 -srcstoretype JKS -deststoretype PKCS12 -deststorepass password*
5. Importing the PKCS12 into CACERTS (this is where i get the error)

   *keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass MY-KEYSTORE-PASS -destkeystore cacerts -srckeystore abc03.dc.abc.com.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12
       keytool -importkeystore -deststorepass MY-KEYSTORE-PASS -destkeystore cacerts -srckeystore abc03.dc.abc.com.p12 -srcstoretype PKCS12*

Can you advise me on how to fix this or is there another way of doing it. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

There are two tools that might help:

- http://portecle.sourceforge.net/
- https://keystore-explorer.org/index.html